# Math Equation with Python

Tags: python, math, equation

I'm trying to obtain solution for math equation with python such as follows:

```
# Open netCDF file
fd1 = nc.Dataset(nc_file1, 'r')

# Read variables from the netCDF file
rng1 = fd1.variables['range'][:]
tim1 = fd1.variables['time'][:]
pwr1 = fd1.variables['pwr'][:]
dpl1 = fd1.variables['dpl'][:]
nfft1 = fd1.variables['nfft'][0]
pn1 = fd1.variables['pnoise'][:]

# Close netCDF file

fd1.close()

# Specify beam 
ibeam1 = 0

# Time convertion from seconds to hours
tim1 = tim1/3600.0

# Select data and transpose
p_plot1 = pwr1[ibeam1]
for it1 in range(len(tim1)):
   p_plot1[it1] = p_plot1[it1] - pn1[ibeam1][it1] - 10.*np.log10(nfft1)
p_plot1 = p_plot1.transpose() 

**#Determine Height**
A=6378.1370
Tetha=math.cos((37.5 * math.pi) / 180)
for j in range(len(tim1)):
   for i in range(len(rng1)):
       D[i]=sqrt(A**2+(rng1[i]**2)+(2*A*(rng1[i])*Tetha)
       height1(i,j)=(D[i]-A)
```

From the math equation (Determine Height) I got error. It might be of syntax for equation in python. Actually, I focused on three variable of data that is tim1, rng1, and pwr1. From rng1 data I will obtain height1, just by convert rng1 to height1 by using that equation.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: `D[i]=sqrt(A**2+(rng1[i]**2)+(2*A*(rng1[i])*Tetha)` needs an extra `)` at the end

Comment: Not just an extra ). Because after I gave an extra one, still have an error for the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the row

```
D[i]=sqrt(A**2+(rng1[i]**2)+(2*A*(rng1[i])*Tetha)
```

The parentheses don't match up, just add one at the end like this and it will work.

```
D[i]=sqrt(A**2+(rng1[i]**2)+(2*A*(rng1[i])*Tetha))
```

Comment: Not just an extra ). Because after I gave an extra one, still have an error for the last line

Comment: `height1(i,j)` is a function call, is perhaps height1 meant to be a two-dimensional array? In that case it would be `height1[i][j]`

Comment: Yes, correct. Height1 is one dimensional array. So, I can revise the last script like this: height1[i]=(D-A). Thank you all.